# Does C11 allow variable declarations at any place in a function?

Tags: c, c11, variable-declaration

Does the C11 standard (note I don't mean C++11) allow you to declare variables at any place in a function?

The code below is not valid in ANSI C (C89, C90):

```
int main()
{
  printf("Hello world!");
  int a = 5; /* Error: all variables should be declared at the beginning of the function. */
  return 0;
}
```

Is it valid source code in C11?

Comment: Why is it not valid ANSI C? Did ANSI somehow refuse to update their national standard to follow C99?

Comment: Is is valid ANSI C if you have the correct understanding of what ANSI C means. ANSI updates there standard well to the most recent version. Unfortunately in urban slang the term "ANSI C" incorrectly stuck to C 89.

Comment: @JensGustedt: An alternative way of looking at it is that ANSI C was indeed C89, but since 1990, the standard has been ISO C, and ANSI has endorsed ISO C as the standard. The difference between ISO C 90 and ANSI C 89 was in the section numbering, AFAIK; otherwise, the text was unchanged. But that's splitting hairs.  GCC uses `-ansi` as a synonym for `-std=c89` and doesn't recognize `-std=c90` (but most versions of GCC recognize `std=c99` and some recent ones recognize `-std=c11`). POSIX used to require a `c89` C compiler; it currently requires a `c99` compiler because it has not been revised.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. This was already valid in C99 (see the second bullet [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Design)).

Answer (score 5):

More or less.  C99 introduced the ability to declare variables part way through a block and in the first section of a `for` loop, and C2011 has continued that.

```
void c99_or_later(int n, int *x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  // C99 or later
    {
         printf("x[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
         int t = x[i];           // C99 or later
         x[0] = x[i];
         x[i] = t;
    }
}
```

You might also note that the C++ style tail comments are only valid in C99 or later, too.

If you have to deal with C compilers that are not C99 compliant (MSVC, for example), then you can't use these (convenient) notations.  GCC provides you with a useful warning flag: `-Wdeclaration-after-statement`.

Note that you cannot put a declaration immediately after a label (C11 [§6.8.1 Labelled statements](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.1)); you cannot label a declaration, or jump to a declaration.  See also [§6.8.2 Compound statement](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.2), [§6.7 Declarations](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7) and [§6.9 External definitions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9).  However, you can label an empty statement, so it isn't a major problem:

```
label: ;
    int a = 5;
```