# function return multi value to main function

Tags: c, return

This code is a part of my main code , in this part, each product code that user enter , the quantity and total price will increase, at the end, the user return totalSum, quantity1,quantity2,quantity3,quantity4 to main function,then proceed to print receipt , I know to return to main function have to do like this `z= getTotalSum()`. but how for multi return? (currently I put as 0 because I don't know how to put)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getTotalSum (void); // when user selected product will calculate sum,quantity of each product
int main ()
{
getTotalSum();
return 0;
}
int getTotalSum (void)
{
int code;
float sum=0,totalSum,quantity1=0,quantity2=0,quantity3=0,quantity4=0;
while(1)
{   
    printf("Enter a product code.(Enter 5 to get total sum)\n");
    scanf("%d",&code);

    switch(code)
    {
    case 1:
        {
        quantity1=( quantity1 + 1);
        sum=( 45.20 + sum);
        printf("Current Sum: RM%.2f\n",sum);
        break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
        quantity2=( quantity2 + 1);
        sum=(14.50 + sum);
        printf("Current Sum: RM%.2f\n",sum);
        break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
        quantity3=( quantity3 + 1);
        sum=(3.45 + sum);
        printf("Current Sum: RM%.2f\n",sum);
        break;
        }
    case 4:
        {
        quantity4=( quantity4 + 1);
        sum=(7.80 + sum);
        printf("Current Sum: RM%.2f\n",sum);
        break;
        }
    case 5:
        totalSum= sum;
        printf("+--------------+--------------------+----------+\n");
        printf("| Product Code | Rentail Price (RM) | Quantity |\n");
        printf("+--------------+--------------------+----------+\n");
        printf("| 1            | 45.20              | %.f        |\n",quantity1);
        printf("+--------------+--------------------+----------+\n");
        printf("| 2            | 14.50              | %.f        |\n",quantity2);
        printf("+--------------+--------------------+----------+\n");
        printf("| 3            |  3.45              | %.f        |\n",quantity3);
        printf("+--------------+--------------------+----------+\n");
        printf("| 4            |  7.80              | %.f        |\n",quantity4);
        printf("+--------------+--------------------+----------+\n");
        printf("Total Sum: RM%.2f\n",totalSum); 
        return 0;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't return multiple values, but you can send multiple variables by reference and change them in the function.

Comment: Alternatively, you may bundle your return values in a `struct` and then you can return them from function as one return value.

Comment: What are the "multi" values you want to return?  Please provide an example.

Comment: @chux _totalSum, quantity1,quantity2,quantity3,quantity4_

Comment: @Scheff thank you for suggestion , can you show me how to do it because I'm learning to code , and your suggestion sounds like a new thing to me.

Comment: This is shown in option 1 of Fiddling Bits.

Comment: Shown applied to your sample: [Live Demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/XmHEkY).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is _RM_? Malaysian Ringgit? (In Germany, it was the common abbr. for [Reichsmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichsmark) but it isn't valid cash for a long time anymore.) It looks confusingly familiar somehow. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff thank you for your sample , but when I try run it , it show error ,picture: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DsGghJR782AkMjHRj_r5a-jRo7A0oVNU/view?usp=sharing) , yes it is Ringgit Malaysia

Comment: Sorry, I'm still in company and our company's firewall doesn't let me "through" your link. I just clicked the [Live Demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/XmHEkY) - it looks as expected. Can you describe textually what do you think is wrong?

Comment: It says **1) error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'**  and the error pointer point to `int code; if (scanf("%d", &code) != 1) continue;` **2) error C2065: 'code' : undeclared identifier** and the error pointer point to  `int code; if (scanf("%d", &code) != 1) continue;` (same line) **3) error C2065: 'code' : undeclared identifier** and the error pointer point to `switch(code) {` . These are error message show , and I run it in c using microsoft visual studio 2010.

Comment: OK. This is probably C11 on ideone where you can [declare a variable at any place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13111033/7478597). So, move the `int code;` to an appropriate place (after `{`) and it should work.

Comment: Microsoft ignored any (modern) C standard for a long time. Currently, they seem to catch up a bit but I'm not sure about their progress... ;-) (I'm using C++ in daily work where I know a bit better.)

Comment: @Scheff It works now , thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. You may accept the answer of Fiddling Bits as it's IMHO correct and encompassing.

Comment: @Scheff This is my main code : [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gg54msQX3yjj0Rqowp06b0qSxaViuHKO) I have 'installed' your code in it , It works and I forgot to ask : your code I use it in option 1 and then when I want to make it as input of option 3, how to do that ?

Comment: Sorry, I may not follow your link. (Company's firewall.) You can post it on [ideone](https://ideone.com).

Comment: @Scheff never mind , I have figure it out ,sorry for disturb you. Have a nice day :-)

Comment: @Scheff This is my main code [link](https://ideone.com/1OzheV) , at line 156 to 169 , I have a function for confirm total sum , it use to help user if user found the total sum is not correct , it can re-enter and then confirm again, if confirmed, it exit to main function , my problem is where I should insert this function because when I try to insert it didn't work as my expectation, or maybe is there any modify I need to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods you may employ to `return` multiple values:

1. `return` a `struct`
2. Write to several variables passed to function by address
3. Write to `struct` passed to function by address
4. Write to an array passed to function

An example of each follows:

**1**

```
struct data
{
    int one;
    int two;
    int three;
    int four;
};

struct data getTotalSum(void)
{
    ...
}
```

**2**

```
void getTotalSum(int *one, int *two, int *three, int *four)
{
    ...
}
```

**3**

```
struct data
{
    int one;
    int two;
    int three;
    int four;
};

void getTotalSum(struct data *d)
{
    ...
}
```

**4**

```
void getTotalSum(int *array)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Solely that you created instances (named 'data') of anonymous structs (or forgot the `typedef`)...

Comment: @Aconcagua Forgot the syntax. Danke schön.

Comment: You could also write to a variable in the global space.

Comment: @JasonBrown On one hand, you are completely right. On the other hand, it might be worth not to encourage this as it's in most cases bad style. May be, it's even better to make it a secret...